# Unable to change "add to cart" text in button prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm incapable to change the text on these buttons, I'm looking in translations in the theme, but no clue about how to find this specific text and I'm spending a lot of time trying to locate it, I'm using prestashop 1.7.6

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: change through admin -> transaltion -> select active theme -> eidt and save.
After save, make sure to delete all cache from admin and then check.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the classic theme, you have to go to translations in the admin panel.
In the lists, choose :

- type : "front-office" or "theme translation"
- theme : "classic"
- language : * yours *

And click on the "modify" button.

Then, the "add-to-cart" label is in "Shop" -> "Theme" -> "Actions" at the second page.

Or, you can simply search for "add to cart" in the search bar.